# Manipulating an object with a method in another class

Tags: c#

Hi I'm very new to c# and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I have created a text box with the value "Total" set to 0 in my main class, and I have created a button "button1_Click" in my "AddFunds" class in which I want it to change the Total value by reading in what the user has in putted "Deposit" putting through a loop and incrementing the "Total". How do I get the AddFunds class to recognize the int Total in my main class?

```
public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Total = new int();
        Total = 0;

        ////string str = Convert.ToString(Total);
        ////Total.Text = str;

    }

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int Deposit = 0; Deposit <= 0; ++Deposit)
        {
            Total = Deposit;
        }
    }

    public void richTextBox1_TextChanged(int initialDeposit)
    {

        int Deposit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    }
```

Comment: *I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.* Grab CLR Via C#, skip the first two chapters, and start reading.  Trust me.

Comment: @Will Thanks ill go check that out.

Comment: `Total` is only in the scope of `textBox1_TextChanged`, which is not a class.  `textBox1_TextChanged` is a method, which resides in a class.

Answer (score 0):

You have some ways of doing that, but remember if this classes you're talking about are forms, they need to exist simultaneously, anything else will end up on you trying to access a null reference.

1. You can create a public property Total on your main class and pass an instace of Main to AddFund
2. If the composition is the oposite as the above, and Main holds an instance of AddFund you can make Main inject itself on the other class or pass a Funciotn to AddFund so it can access the value
3. This one is the only one that doesn't sound like a code smell given the information you provided, abstract your logic to some classes that are not forms and manipulate them on the forms.